# Export ggplot with complete background image in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this scatterplot using ggplot2 and the `mtcars` example.

```
ggmtcars <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point(size=2, shape=23) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Now, I want to introduce a background image by using `draw_image()` from the `cowplot` package. The image is a open-source image from the Wikimedia Commons repository (copy all the link and paste in the bar).

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2018_Honda_Jazz_(GK5_MY18)_VTi-S_hatchback_(2018-08-06)_01.jpg

I saved the picture with the name `coche.jpg`.

Now I select that image as the background of the scatterplot, which include the entire image in the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(magick)

ggdraw() +
  draw_image("images/coche.jpg",
             scale = 1) +
  draw_plot(ggmtcars)
```

[image]

If I increase the scale of the image (doubling it)

```
ggoverlap <- ggdraw() +
  draw_image("images/coche.jpg",
             scale = 2) +
  draw_plot(ggmtcars)
```

[image]

Now, if I save the latest with `ggsave()` in `.svg` format, the image is cropped.

```
ggsave(file="test.svg", plot=ggoverlap)
```

[image]

My question is:

- How can I export into .svg format the plot and the entire background image?

Comment: Instead of scaling up the image, you should change the plot size by utilizing the `height` and `width` parameters in `draw_plot`